JQuery draggable falling out of sync with cursor when drop zones are revealed
I'm trying to achieve a set up in which dragging a div reveals the drop-zones onto which it can be placed. Trouble is, when a drop zone above the draggable origin is revealed, it pushes the div the distance of its height down from the cursor which makes for an odd UX.
Code below for replication - any clues?


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".goal").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 1000,
    refreshPositions: true,
    start: function() {
      $('.drop_zone').show();
    },
    stop: function() {
      $('.drop_zone').hide();
    }
  });

  $(".drop_zone").droppable({
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).after(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
.bucket {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.goal {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: move;
}

.drop_zone {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted #999;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="ambition">
  <div class="bucket">
    <div class="drop_zone"></div>
    <div class="goal" draggable="true">Goal 1</div>
    <div class="drop_zone"></div>
    <div class="goal" draggable="true">Goal 2</div>
    <div class="drop_zone"></div>
    <div class="goal" draggable="true">Goal 3</div>
    <div class="drop_zone"></div>
    <div class="goal" draggable="true">Goal 4</div>
  </div>
</div>




When elements are hidden in this way, they are not rendered in the page. When it is shown, it is then rendered and this changed the DOM. The Drag element is still a child of the parent, so this change moves the element away from the mouse. May need to detach the element, then show the dropzones. You may also consider using Sortable for this as well.

You should consider switching to Sortable for this.


$(function() {
  $(".bucket").sortable({
    placeholder: "drop_zone"
  });
});
.bucket {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.goal {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: move;
}

.drop_zone {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px dotted #999;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="ambition">
  <div class="bucket">
    <div class="goal">Goal 1</div>
    <div class="goal">Goal 2</div>
    <div class="goal">Goal 3</div>
    <div class="goal">Goal 4</div>
  </div>
</div>



